# ERROR in src/providers/af.ts(2,9): error TS2305: Module

Tags: nodejs, electron

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un problema, para iniciar con npm run electron, ya elimine node_module y volvi a dar npm install y ni así, de ante mano gracias.